# Check list for X same elements in a row

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of booleans and need to edit this list depending on how many True's there are in a row (if the length isn't found, I need to change the boolean to False). I have some really ugly code that currently works (I think for all cases, but have a feeling some number will break it because it's so wonky), but I wanted to see if anyone has a concise and better way of handling all possibilities.

Here's an example:

```
num_in_a_row = 3
my_list = [True True False True True True False True]
```

For the values in my_list, I need to go from start to finish and check if there are AT LEAST num_in_a_row True's, and if not, change the value to False. So my_list, should look like this at the end:

```
my_new_list = [False False False True True True False False]
```

It would change the first two True's because there aren't 3 in a row to False, same with the last True. But the three True's in a row would survive. If the number in a row check was 2, it'd look like this:

```
num_in_a_row = 2
my_list = [True True False True True True False True]
my_new_list = [True True False True True True False False]
```

Any ideas on how to do this in a clean way that's flexible enough to adapt to any value given for the num_in_a_row variable?

Comment: Can't really follow the question, but I'd put money on those being some kind of numpy arrays and not python lists. Every example would crash if you tried to define lists like you have, that looks more like a `print` output from arrays.

Comment: @roganjosh I tried to make it as generic as possible, so these are completely random lists I made up that mimic the data I actually have. However, I don't see how lists vs arrays would substantially change the question as a whole. Maybe read the examples again, and you'll have a helpful idea at a solution.

Comment: Try `my_new_list = [False False False True True True False False]` in REPL or a Python script. Your issue aside, that is not valid syntax.

Comment: Yes, please don't post code that you didn't copy and paste from your IDE after verifying that it runs. Now we cannot copy+paste from your question without fixing your syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `itertools` like so:

```
from itertools import groupby, repeat

run_len = 3
foo = [True, True, False, True, True, True, False, True]

# enumerate runs of the same value in format (value, length)
runs = [(value, len(list(group))) for value, group in groupby(foo)]
print(runs) # [(True, 2), (False, 1), (True, 3), (False, 1), (True, 1)]

# expand that list of runs with your criteria about minimum length
res = sum([list(repeat(value and run >= run_len, run)) for value, run in runs], [])
print(res) # [False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False]
```

See it running here: https://repl.it/repls/StarryDecisiveCharacters

Comment: Thanks, this gets me where I need to go with this!